# Go to Native Edit Contact from app

Tags: ios, edit, contacts

I'm showing AddressBook in my app and want to let the user to edit his/her numbers by opening the Edit View of the Native Phone app in iOS devices. I searched for it but haven't find any answer for that. Is it any way to go to the edit page ? if yes, how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using AddressBook Framework then you can use the  `ABPersonViewController`

You can set the `allowsEditing` property to YES so that you can edit the contact.

> FYI: Adressbook Framework is deprecated from iOS9

If you are using the new Contacts Framework then you can use the 
`CNContactViewController`

```
- (void)displayContactInfoWithEditing: (id)sender {
    ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
    personController.displayedPerson = yourABPersonRefHere;
    personController.addressBook = yourABAddressBookRefHere;
    personController.allowsEditing = YES;
    personController.personViewDelegate = self;

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController: personController animated: YES];
}
```

References: [ABPersonViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ABPersonViewController/allowsEditing), [CNContactViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CNContactViewController)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay @iPrabu , the problem is ABpersonViewController opens the ViewController and I should click on edit button to start editing , is there any other way to go directly to the edit mode ?

Comment: OK i changed it to ABNewPersonViewController and now it is exactly what i was looking for ! cheers mate :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with AddressBook. I think you can do it with `ABPersonViewController` or `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`.

AddressBook is deprecated in iOS 9, and replaced by `Contacts Framework`: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328

If you go to the 2015 WWDC video for `Contacts Framework`: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-223/, and fast forward to 28:10 - you'll see the user contact, and that you can edit it. If that is the UI you want, then I'm think `CNContactViewController` and `CNContactPickerViewController` is what you are looking for.